# How can I reduce time complexity on this algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have this exercise and the goal is to solve it with complexity less than O(n^2).

You have an array with length N filled with event probabilities. Create another array in which for each element i calculate the probability of all event to happen until the position i.

I have coded this O(n^2) solution. Any ideas how to improve it?

```
probabilityTable = [0.1, 0.54, 0.34, 0.11, 0.55, 0.75, 0.01, 0.06, 0.96]

finalTable = list()

for i in range(len(probabilityTable)):
    finalTable.append(1)
    for j in range(i):
        finalTable[i] *= probabilityTable[j]

for item in finalTable:
    print(item)
```

Comment: Is it correct that you never use the last probability?

Comment: Is "n" a typo and you meant "N"?

Comment: How is that a probability table when the sum of the elements exceeds 1?

Comment: @pjs It's just a table, not a distribution. If it were a distribution, and the events were mutually exclusive, would it even make sense to talk about multiple events happening?

Comment: @KellyBundy probabilities are always values between 0 and 1, by definition. And yes, you can have a distribution associated with multiple outcomes, it’s called a joint probability distribution. Joint distributions still have the property that the total amount of probability in the event space is 1. The fact that we’re debating this tells me that the question is too vague.

Comment: @pjs If I have a table of three probabilities, one for winning the lottery, one for being struck by lightning, and one for my computer crashing, why would the sum need to be 1? And I don't see what your point is with a joint probability distribution, why you'd ask about multiple mutually exclusive joint events to occur.

Comment: @KellyBundy If this is a table of event probabilities, the events are alternatives to each other. Unless there’s some further explanation (which should be provided), at least one of them will happen. It’s also possible that two or more could happen, making joint probabilities appropriate. Using your example, having a lightning strike certainly could affect the likelihood of your computer crashing - a conditional probability. The point is, OP has not told us that the events are mutually exclusive, in fact they have slung around the two terms “events” and “probabilities” without defining context

Comment: @pjs "at least one of them will happen" - I don't think that's true. I believe there are people who never win the lottery, never get struck by lightning, and never have a computer crash. You seem to insist that the table must be a distribution, like probabilities of colors when drawing a ball, like 0.3 for red, 0.2 for green and 0.5 for blue. Although then it's unclear why you say "at least one" instead of "exactly one". And again, it doesn't make sense to ask for multiple. You can't draw a red ball *and* a green ball when drawing one ball.

Comment: @KellyBundy You’re making my point for me. We have not been given enough info to know whether these are disjoint events, independent events, or jointly distributed events. The code provided is multiplying probabilities, which by the fundamental laws of probability is only valid if they are independent probabilities, in which case they are **not** disjoint. The point is, OP has not provided sufficient info.

Comment: @pjs I'm not making your point, I'm just pointing out how you're wrong. The only unclear thing is what your problem is. They have a table with probabilities like my example with three, and there's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @KellyBundy Read a basic probability text. Disjoint events have probabilities that sum. Independent events have probabilities that multiply. Anything else requires conditional probabilities or joint distributions. Total probability in an event space equals 1. If you don’t follow those rules, you’re not talking about probability.

Comment: @pjs Maybe you should've read fewer, as you're apparently trying to see something there that you're used to even though it's simply not there. Their table has nine probabilities, one for each of nine events. Independent, as their code shows. There's no need for the sum to be 1. If you looked at the table of the 512 (that's 2⁹) joint probabilities, those would sum to 1, but that's not what this is.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
probabilityTable = [0.1, 0.54, 0.34, 0.11, 0.55, 0.75, 0.01, 0.06, 0.96]

finalTable = probabilityTable.copy()

for i in range(1, len(probabilityTable)):
    finalTable[i] = finalTable[i] * finalTable[i - 1]

for item in finalTable:
    print(item)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
new_probs = [probabilityTable[0]]
for prob in probabilityTable[1:]:
    new_probs.append(new_probs[-1] + prob)
```